# .net Core C# Linux Copy Windows File Permissions (ACL)

Tags: c#, linux, file, .net-core, permissions

I am running a .net Core 3.1 application on a Debian 10 Server. The application has to copy a given Windows source Directory to a Windows network drive. When copying the files and Directories, it has to set the Destination Files and Directories acl to the Source acl.

I tried doing this using Mono.Unix. To access the Windows Network drive on Linux, I mounted to a Diretory in /media.

```
// get Source Directories Info
var unixSrcDirInfo = new Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo(dir.FullName);

//get Destination Directory info
var unixDestDirInfo = new Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo(destinationDir);

//set Destination Directory File Permissions to Source Directory File Permission
unixDestDirInfo.FileAccessPermissions = unixSrcDirInfo.FileAccessPermissions;

unixDestDirInfo.Refresh();
```

Does somebody have an Idea how to copy the ACL of a file on a Linux Machine?

I tried using System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, but that's not allowed on Linux. I tried using Mono.Unix, but it doesn't copy the permissions.

I just want to set the Destination Directorys ACL to the Source Directorys ACL.

Comment: I doubt that's going to work, since the mount point doesn't provide them. The mounted directory doesn't see the ACLs, so you cannot copy them (regardless of what tool/language you use for it)

Comment: Yeah it seems so, I ended up using a Windows Server, so everything is ACL.